# Another Error with redefining

Tags: c++

```
struct PayInfo
{
    int hours;
    double payRate;
};

struct PayRoll
{
    PayRoll();
    int empNumber;
    string name;
    double grossPay;

    PayInfo pay;
};

void GrossPay(PayRoll employee[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        employee[i].grossPay = employee[i].pay.hours *
                            employee[i].pay.payRate;
    }
}

int main()
{
    PayRoll employee[3];        //Problem is here.*****

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the employee's number: " << endl;
        cin >> employee[i].empNumber;

        cout << "Enter the employee's name: " << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, employee[i].name);

        cout << "How many  hours did the employee work?" << endl;
        cin >> employee[i].pay.hours;

        cout << "What is the employee's hourly pay rate?" << endl;
        cin >> employee[i].pay.payRate;
    }

    GrossPay(employee);

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        cout << "Here is the employee's payroll data:\n";
        cout << "name: " << employee[j].name << endl;
        cout << "Number: " << employee[j].empNumber << endl;
        cout << "hours worked: " << employee[j].pay.hours << endl;
        cout << "Hourly pay rate: " << employee[j].pay.payRate << endl;
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
        cout << "Gross Pay: $" << employee[j].grossPay << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

ERROR: Undefined Reference to PayRoll::PayRoll()'
How do I fix this now?
I was trying to make an array with a nested Structure.
Never got to use structure that much that's why I am having lots of difficulty.

Comment: You've declared a default constructor for PayRoll but you haven't defined it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a **definition** for the constructor `PayRoll::PayRoll`.

```
PayRoll::PayRoll() {}
```

If you're using C++11, you can explicitly default it:

```
struct PayRoll
{
    PayRoll() = default;
    // ...
```

Comment: Or just don't declare it at all (unless you want it to do something non-trivial, or unless you want to declare another constructor and still have a default one).